# Split requirements files in pip

Tags: python, syntax, installation, pip, package-management

To create Python virtual environments I use virtualenv and pip. The workflow is very simple:

```
$ virtualenv project
$ cd project
$ . bin/activate
$ pip install -r /path/to/requirements/req1.txt
$ pip install -r /path/to/requirements/req2.txt
```

The number of different requirement files can grow enough to make handy to have a way to include them at once, so I'd rather prefer to say:

```
$ pip install -r /path/to/requirements/req1_req2.txt
```

with `req1_req2.txt` containing something like:

```
include /path/to/requirements/req1.txt
include /path/to/requirements/req2.txt
```

or otherwise:

```
$ pip install -r /path/to/requirements/*.txt
```

None of that works and however much simple it could be, I can't figure out how to do what I want.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What about script which accept input like req1|req2... split it and then call os.system with proper pip command ?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The `-r` flag isn't restricted to command-line use only, it can also be used inside requirements files. So running `pip install -r req-1-and-2.txt` when req-1-and-2.txt contains this:

```
-r req-1.txt
-r req-2.txt
```

will install everything specified in req-1.txt and req-2.txt.

Comment: Can this be used to extend and overwrite? E.g. req-1.txt specifies `foo==1.3` and req-2.txt `foo==1.4`, would it install 1.4?

Comment: Answering my own question: No, it doesn't work: `Double requirement given: foo==1.4 ...`

Comment: @beluga.me it works IF your pip has the fix. If you have pip 1.5.X which is default for say Debian wheezy or jessie, than doing *pip install -U pip* (or similar) should fix this problem.

Answer (score 11):

Just on a note, you can also split the requirements based on your groupings and embed them in a single file ( or again can prepare multiple requirements file based on your environment), that you can execute.

For example, the test requirements here:

**requirements-test.txt**

```
pylint==2.4.4
pytest==5.3.2
```

The dev requirements here:

**requirements-dev.txt**

```
boto3>=1.12.11
```

Master requirements file containing your other requirements:

**requirements.txt**

```
-r requirements-dev.txt
-r requirements-test.txt
```

Now, you can just install the requirements file embedding your other requirements

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```