# Recursive requirements in python within the same project?

Tags: python

Silly question here.

Let's say I want to structure my project into multiple sub-projects. I wish to specify dependencies for each of the projects, but wish to have the whole be available as one cohesive unit as well.

So, for example:

```
Project
|- setup.py
|- requirements.txt
|- Subproject1
   |- requirements.txt
   |- code.py 
|- Subproject2
   |- requirements.txt
   |- foo.py
```

So, instead of specifying dependencies all in a root file, I want to specify them in each subproject. Is this possible?

Comment: I've re-read the question multiple times, and I am struggling to understand it. What exactly do you mean by "specifying dependencies"?

Comment: Say `Subproject1` uses a twitter library, while `Subproject2` needs some xml library. Instead of the root project specifying both, I want each subproject to list their own.

Comment: Oh, this is about `pip`? If it is, you might mention it rather than having the reader figure it out themselves. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are speaking of something like `pip install -r whole-project-requirements.txt`, where `whole-project-requirements.txt` hold references to subprojects dependencies, it seems possible, as described in [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704287/split-requirements-files-in-pip) will help you