# PIP: How to Cascade Requirements Files and Use Private Indexes?

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I am trying to deploy a Django app to Heroku where one of the required packages lives on `https://testpypi.python.org/pypi` and of course Django is on the main PyPI server.

My setup looks like this.

```
# requirements.txt
-r requirements/req2.txt
-r requirements/req3.txt
```

```
# requirements/req2.txt
Django==1.7.7
```

```
# requirements/req3.txt
-i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
foo-bar==0.4
```

Running the command: `pip install -r requirements.txt` results in the following error.

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement 
Django==1.7.7 (from -r ./requirements/req2.txt (line 2))
No distributions at all found for Django==1.7.7 
(from -r ./requirements/req2.txt (line 2))
```

So to me it looks like the `-i` argument in `req3` is being set then pip tries to look for Django on the `testpypi` server.

I tried adding `-i https://pypi.python.org/pypi` to `req2.txt` but I still get the same error. *(perhaps `https://pypi.python.org/pypi` is the wrong url)*

In addition if I run either `req*.txt` file individually the installation of the package is successful?

**How can one cascade requirements files and use private indexes?**

Admittedly [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704287/split-requirements-files-in-pip) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803829/how-to-customize-a-requirements-txt-for-multiple-environments) are quite similar but neither deal with private indexs

Comment: I am voting to close this question as I believe it is an XY question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289695/pip-how-to-install-packages-from-multiple-servers-from-a-requirements-file. is a better version of the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the correct method of dealing with private indexes is to use `--extra-index-url` switch. From the [documentation of pip](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html#indexes-find-links):

> Note that using --index-url removes the use of PyPI, while using --extra-index-url will add additional indexes.

So, putting the line

```
--extra-index-url https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
```

on top of your `requirements.txt` should be enough. No need to cascade at all!

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm both locally and when deploying to heroku.