# Installing Packages from Multiple Servers from One or More Requirements File

Tags: python, pip

I have tried the following two approaches without success.

The first with Cascading Requirements Files.

```
# requirements.txt
-r requirements/req2.txt
-r requirements/req3.txt
```

```
# requirements/req2.txt
Django==1.7.7
```

```
# requirements/req3.txt
-i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
foo-bar==0.4
```

`pip install -r requirements.txt` results in `pip` not finding Django.

The second attempt was to include both requirements in a single file:

```
-i https://pypi.python.org/pypi/
Django==1.7.7
-i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
foo-bar==0.4
```

`pip install -r requirements.txt` results in the same error, `pip` not finding Django.

How can I use `pip` to install packages from different servers/index-urls?

Comment: I needed it for deployment to Heroku. To install application dependencies Heroku will call `pip install -r requirements.txt`, as such I needed to define packages on multiple indexs under one `pip` readable entry point. I can  image other uses too, but I am pretty new to the Python community so I am hesitant to speculate. I spent a couple of hours yesterday trying to figure out how to do this, so I though I would share the findings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution in either case is to add `--extra-index-url <url>` at the beginning of the `requirements.txt` file.

Example:

```
# requirements.txt
--extra-index-url https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Django==1.7.7
django-stackexchange-feed==0.4
```

Or to use Cascading Requirements Files:

```
# requirements.txt
--extra-index-url https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
-r requirements/req2.txt
-r requirements/req3.txt
```

```
# requirements/req2.txt
Django==1.7.7
```

```
# requirements/req3.txt
foo-bar==0.4
```

`pip install -r requirements.txt` will now work.

Comment: So theres no way to explicitly require that a package comes from a specific index, and fails if *that specific index* doesnt have it?