# pip 9.0.1 installs old version even with --no-cache-dir? (test server)

Tags: pip

I am learning how to upload (and then install) python packages, and I created a package and uploaded it to PyPi **test** server:

```
https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/mom
```

Currently, there are a few versions there, the newest of which is 3.1.22. I uploaded both `sdist` and `bdist-wheel` using `twine`:

```
twine upload dist/* -r testpypi --skip-existing
Uploading distributions to https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading mom-3.1.22-py3-none-any.whl
Uploading mom-3.1.22.tar.gz
```

At some point, every attempt to install started resulting in it trying to install an older version, which I had since deleted:

```
    pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/pypi mom --no-cache-dir -vvv
    ...
    Found link https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/48/2454ff318d4dca8b5025ab3b8e40582f9216bc08471c7f48e3c91e3f7791/
    mom-3.1.17a1-py3-none-any.whl (from https://test.pypi.org/project/mom/),version: 3.1.17a1
    Found link https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/08/2fd1d7fefc7f22085236d86ad7c5b5daee3f2a5e6a1f53bc6669463e0e33/
    mom-3.1.17a1.tar.gz (from https://test.pypi.org/project/mom/), version: 3.1.17a1
```

It would seem that `--no-cache-dir` should help, and indeed I had this issue the other day and was able to solve it with `--no-cache-dir`, and yet now the issue persists.

What can be the reason(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561435/1861884) by [pylang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4531270/pylang) helped me: instead of installing with the `-i` option, packages from the test server can be installed with the `--extra-index-url` option.