# Error installing required modules from setuptools (matplolib)

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I am developing a python library that I wish to distribute afterwards. In order to do this I am configuring setuptools. Currently I am testing all this in a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.0.4.2 after doing an update & upgrade.

The problem is that my setup.py looks like this (I defined the oldest available package):

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
    'setuptools>=40.0.0',
    'matplotlib>=1.0.1',
    'numpy>=1.3.0',
    'scipy>=0.8.0',
    ],
    ...
)
```

and when I install my package from test.pypi I get this error with matplotlib:

```
Collecting LIB_TEST_NEW
  Using cached https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/6a/d3f7569c437b70e4c048e8597977c3d42e9baa1151c0245f210cb6e529f1/LIB_TEST_NEW-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting matplotlib>=1.0.1 (from LIB_TEST_NEW)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib>=1.0.1 (from LIB_TEST_NEW) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib>=1.0.1 (from LIB_TEST_NEW)
```

I have tried both with and without specifying the version of the modules and also defining the modules in a separate requirements.txt.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip install from pypi works, but from testpypi fails (cannot find requirements)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514703/pip-install-from-pypi-works-but-from-testpypi-fails-cannot-find-requirements)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

After some digging I found a [solution](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-testpypi/#using-testpypi-with-pip).

"If you want to allow pip to also pull other packages from PyPI you can specify --extra-index-url to point to PyPI. This is useful when the package you’re testing has dependencies:"

Then using:

```
pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple your-package
```

Solved my error. Hope it helps someone.