# pip install is looking for required dependency within the package

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, pypi, python-packaging

I'm build up my package with setup.py, in which it has a `install_requires=get_requirements('requirements.txt')`, and in the `requirements.txt`, the first required dependency is `bottle==0.12.18`.

Then I ran

```
python setup.py sdist
twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

After uploading succeeded, I installed with `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ my_package==version_num` which gives me the error

```
Collecting bottle==0.12.18 (from mypakage==version_num)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bottle==0.12.18 (from mypakage==version_num) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bottle==0.12.18 (from mypakage==version_num)
```

Looks like it's looking for the dependency within my package, which will definitely fail. This error suddenly started happening and I've never seen this before. Do you have any idea why it's happening and how can I make it look for dependency in a way like `pip install -r requirements`?

Comment: try `--extra-index-url` instead of `--index-url` -- not many things upload to test pypi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip install from pypi works, but from testpypi fails (cannot find requirements)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514703/pip-install-from-pypi-works-but-from-testpypi-fails-cannot-find-requirements)