# pip install doesn't work without --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/

Tags: python, pip

I have a python package I want to release on pypi. I am able to build without any problem and upload to testpypi and pypi. However,

`pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mypackage==0.0.9` doesn't work. I am getting:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mypackage==0.0.9 (from versions: 0.0.2, 0.0.3, 0.0.8)` 
But I can see 0.0.9 uploaded on the both websites. If I try:

`pip install mypackage==0.0.9` I am getting the same error.

Surprisingly, following line works:

`pip install --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mypackage==0.0.9`

Also, `pip install -e .` just works fine too.

Any guess what might be going wrong? My github download_url in `setup.cfg` is not public yet, could it be related to that?

Comment: I think the question here is: 'pip install fails with `--index-url` to specify test.pypi, but succeeds with `--extra-index-url`.  Out of interest, does this go away with time?  I've seen occasional odd problems with pip immediately after pushing upgrades.

Comment: ah, I think this is the dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514703/pip-install-from-pypi-works-but-from-testpypi-fails-cannot-find-requirements  Note that in your case it seems to have worked without specifying -i in the second case because the package is also on pypi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip install from pypi works, but from testpypi fails (cannot find requirements)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514703/pip-install-from-pypi-works-but-from-testpypi-fails-cannot-find-requirements)

Comment: I hope it goes away. Not really. I saw that question and couple similar ones. Cause even passing `--extra-index-url` solves issues with testpypi. I still get same error when I do `pip install mypackage`

Comment: when I do `pip install -e .` it fetches everything from pypi AFAIK. So I couldn't understand why I am getting this error with `pip install mypackage`.

Comment: I think passing --extra-index-url works in this case because you have the package on both pypi and testpypi with the same versions?  Is it possible that only the testpypi version has the dependencies properly configured?

Comment: pip install -e . is installing the *local* code, not fetching the package from pypi. (' -e, --editable <path/url>   Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode") from a local project path or a VCS url.')

Comment: I pushed the same exact package to both pypi and testpypi. but I tried pushing a version only one website for each and still getting the same error. Do you think I need to check dependency configurations?

Comment: yes `pip install -e .` installs the local code but fetches dependencies from pypi right? my dependencies are same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238947/discussion-between-2e0byo-and-cancode).