# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from fuzzytm) (from versions: none)

Tags: python, pandas, version, pypi

I have created a new version of my package and have uploaded it to Pypi's test server using:

```
python -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

To test if it works, I have created a new virtual environment with Python 3.8 and ran:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ FuzzyTM==0.5.0

(test-pypi) C:\Users\Emil\surfdrive\PhD\3. Python Scripts\GitHub\FuzzyTM>pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ FuzzyTM==0.5.0
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting FuzzyTM==0.5.0
  Using cached https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/8f/7de980d5c61556e96e5277abe687f77a40cc967a8a618f0e5fc08470b492/FuzzyTM-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting pyfume
  Using cached https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/48/9e/52632652961866263f1b61b7f8c55c50992696e3cde224617a7563287d94/pyFUME-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from fuzzytm) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
```

What causes this error? And what can I do to overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. The problem is that `pandas` does not have releases in TestPypi, only in Pypi. You will need to specify the index for your dependencies.

[The solution is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561435/13574635)

Answer (score 0):

It requires: Python version >=3.9

Found on [github.com](https://github.com/gventuri/pandas-ai/issues/173#issuecomment-1564763632) and [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/pandasai/)