# Python package I made installls dist-info instead of the package

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

So I just tried to create my first python package on the testing python package index and when I install the packaged I only get the dist-info. The github is [here](https://github.com/jgore077/Internet-Archive-Uploader) and the its located [here](https://test.pypi.org/project/internet-archive-uploader/1.0/#files) on the testing index.

I'm not sure whats going wrong and I don't even know what sort of query's I would use to resolve this issue so I am looking for support here.

[image: This is a photo of what the package looks like after installing]

As you can see there is no code in the installed package. It should be noted that I am installing the package using the command generated by testing.pypi

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ internet-archive-uploader==1.0
```

I also get this error when installing which I am pretty sure I can resolve by specifying a version of internetarchive in the setup.py

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of internet-archive-uploader to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement internetarchive (from internet-archive-uploader) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for internetarchive
```

Anyways to help anyone who attempts to answer this question I used this powershell script to build the project

```
Remove-Item 'dist' -Confirm
Remove-Item 'internet_archive_uploader.egg-info' -Confirm
pip install -e . 
py -m build
```

Alongside this command to upload it to the package index

```
py -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

I am hoping the issue can be discovered from the source code but If it cant and extra information is needed I am on standby to supply it. Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to mention that I was following this [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: Check the content of the distributions (sdist and most importantly wheel) before considering uploading.

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/jgore077/Internet-Archive-Uploader.git && cd Internet-Archive-Uploader.git && python3.7 -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.find_packages())"` prints `[]` (an empty list). You don't have packages to install so nothing is installed.

Comment: `$ python3.7 -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.find_packages(where='src'))"` => `['InternetArchiveUploader']`

Comment: So I should move my package out of the source folder then go through the build and upload process again?

Comment: @jgore200377 There're many ways to fix your problem. My second comment shows the simplest.

Comment: @phd that worked but I cant figure out this "ERROR: No matching distribution found for internetarchive". I just don't get it because that is a totally valid python package.

Comment: I think its because its on the testing index and the internet archive package isn't on it.

Comment: @jgore200377 https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561435/7976758 `pypi.org` index is not used automatically if you use `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/` so you have to add it explicitly.