When installing packages in Anaconda, I get the error: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dash (from versions: none)
Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dash (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dash
Python version : 3.11.7
Platform : MAC Air

You need to include your platform info (os, cpu).

We need to see the command line. Most probably it was pip install and it seems you gave only one index so pip simply cannot find dash in that index. Add PyPI as an extra index: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561435/7976758
